# Подчеркивание текста ссылок при наведении

Tags: html, css

Как сделать подчеркивание текста ссылки:

```
<ul> 
    <li>
        <a href="">Текст</a>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Если элементы списка представлены `inline-block`'ом и подчеркивание распространяется на весь блок?

Comment: Ссылка - текст, представленный элементом списка ul

Comment: Недостаточно кода для ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `text-decoration: underline;`
На него не влияет свойство `display`;

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xj13v714/)

Answer (score 0):

Также возможно:

**Пример 1** - использовать `border`

```css
ul{
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 15px;
}
ul > li a{    
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'segoe ui';
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
ul > li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f00; /* вместо этого цвета можно использовать любой другой */
}
```

```html
<ul> 
    <li><a href="#">Текст</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Текст</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Текст</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Текст</a></li>
<ul>
```

**Пример 2** - использовать псевдоэлементы - `:before` or `:after`

```css
ul{
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 15px;
}
ul > li a{    
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'segoe ui';
    color: #000;
    position: relative;    
}
ul > li a:hover:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #f00;   
}
```

```html
<ul> 
    <li><a href="#">Текст</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Текст</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Текст</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Текст</a></li>
<ul>
```